# Converting monthly to daily data

Tags: sql, impala

I have monthly data that I would like to transform to daily data. The data looks like this. The extraction_dt is in date format.

| isin | extraction_date | yield |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 2013-01-31 | 100 |
| 001 | 2013-02-28 | 110 |
| 001 | 2013-03-31 | 105 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 002 | 2013-01-31 | 200 |
| ... | ... | ... |

And I would like to have something like this

| isin | extraction_dt | yield |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 2013-01-01 | 100 |
| 001 | 2013-01-02 | 100 |
| 001 | 2013-01-03 | 100 |
| .. | ..... | ... |
| 001 | 2013-02-01 | 110 |
| ... | ... | ... |

I tried the following code but it does not work. I get the error message AnalysisException: Could not resolve table reference: 'cte'. How would you convert monthly to daily data?

```sql
with cte as
(select isin, extraction_dt, yield
 from datashop
 union all
 select isin, extraction_dt, dateadd(d, 1, extraction_dt) AS date_dt, yield
 from cte
 where datediff(m,date_dt,dateadd(d, 1, date_dt))=0
)
select isin, date_dt,
       1.0*isin / count(*) over (partition by isin, date_dt) AS daily_yield
from cte
order by 1,2
```

Comment: In most SQL dialects this would require `with recursive`, not just `with`, not sure about Impala.

Comment: You mean with recursive cte as?

Comment: Yes, but Impala does not seem to support recursive common table expressions.

Comment: recursive wont work in impala. i answered the question for impala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest easy solution.

1. generate a date series
2. match it with your data so it gets repeated.
   So, here is the SQL you can use for Impala.

```
select isin, extraction_dt, a.dt AS date_dt, yield
from 
datashop d,
 (
select now() - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a) + (1000 * d.a) ) DAY as dt
    from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as d
) a
WHERE
from_timestamp(a.dt,'yyyy/MM') =from_timestamp(d.extraction_dt,'yyyy/MM')
order by 1,2,3
```

the alias a is going to generate a series of dates.
`WHERE` - this clause will restrict to the month of extraction_dt. and you will get all possible values for a month.
`ORDER BY` - will show a nice output.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! I do not fully understand your code. I do not understand where you get the numbers 10, 100 and 1000 from and also all the numbers in the select statements in the cross join?

Comment: First we generate a series of numbers like 1,2,3,4... upto 10,000. Then we are deducting it from systemdate(now) so that we can have a series of dates. Series ends on today and goes back to 10,000 day in the past. Similarly you can go in future as well if you want future dates.

Answer (score 1):

Your `WITH` clause has a recursive (self-referencing) query. In most SQL dialects, this requires using `WITH RECURSIVE`, not plain `WITH`. According to the [Impala SQL reference](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_with.html), Impala does not support recursive common table expressions:

> The Impala `WITH` clause does not support recursive queries in the
> `WITH`, which is supported in some other database systems.

In other words, you cannot do this in Impala.

Comment: How would you solve the problem then? I am stuck and do not know how to proceed

Comment: @Lisa You would need to join against a table or table-valued function with all dates in a range. I don't know Impala to answer exactly how to do this.